# vboxmanage running a bat file, but doesn't see arguments

Tags: batch-file, virtualbox

I have a Virtualbox instance running Windows10, and am running the following command from outside of VirtualBox:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" 
    --nologo guestcontrol "Win10_x64" run 
    --exe "\\VBOXSVR\codemodel\VirtualBox_RunInstaller.bat" 
    --username user --password pass 
    --wait-stdout 
    -- VERSION5
```

The argument I am trying to pass to the `VirtualBox_RunInstaller` bat file is `VERSION5`, but `%1` is always empty. I can see this because when `set version=%1` is run, it prints out `set version=`. So it is successfully running the batch file, but no arguments are getting passed to it.

Have I got the syntax wrong? I've tried several variations at this point but haven't got it right yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand [this link](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=32115) correctly the --exe to address is cmd.exe and the batch file has to be the first argument (to the exe)

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" ^
    --nologo guestcontrol "Win10_x64" run ^
    --exe cmd.exe ^
    --username user --password pass ^
    --wait-stdout ^
    -- "\\VBOXSVR\codemodel\VirtualBox_RunInstaller.bat"  VERSION5
```